# Report Manager - "Select all" as default for some linked reports

Tags: reporting-services, report, query-string

I would like to know if it is possible in report manager to give a specific linked report a "Select all" as default for a parameter.

Here is where i want to set the parameter to select all:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in  Report Builder or Visual Studio:

create the parameter query like:

```
select null as value, '<ALL>' as label
union all
select distinct value, label from xxxxxxxx
```

this will return the values with specific row on the top.

now in your dataset where clause you can set the following and it will return all or whatever is selected:

```
XXXXX=CASE WHEN @parameter IS NULL THEN XXXXX ELSE @parameter END
```

set the XXXXX to the column that provides the parameter info, make sure you set the parameter to accept null values.

Then all you have to do in SSRS is pass null into that parameter

set the default value as 'NULL' in the parameter

There is probably a different, easier way but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do something like this, you will have to provide a list of possible values for the parameter. This can be done either by using the Specify values in the Available Values, or the Get values from a query option, in the parameter properties.

This is done in the report designer, or Report Builder. It cannot be done reliably via Report Manager (like in your screen capture).

Once you have that in place, make sure the default values for the parameter are set to all available values.